# is it possible to execute another route handle before execute current one?

Tags: node.js, express

i was designing an express node app.

suppose i have 2 paths

"/posts/:postId/update"

"/posts/:postId/upload"

i wonder is that possible when people visit the second path,the route can auto run the first path's handle?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could define your routes as such

```
var routes = require('./routes');

app.get('/posts/:postId/update', routes.update);
app.get('/posts/:postId/upload', routes.upload, routes.update);
```

So that inside `routes.upload` you could do something like

```
route.upload = function(req, res, next) {
  // do whatever you need to

  // this will call the next function defined
  // in your route definition, which is update
  next();
};
```

Comment: I like this middleware-based approach.

Comment: by the way,how to determine it is then last route or not?
i try to check as if the next funciton is undefined in order to check as it is the last route,but failed,i aways get next function is not null,even i just visit the path with only one route handle

Comment: I'm not sure about that, what is the requirement?

Comment: i have changed my solution before your anwser.
i used 2 path /posts/:postId/update and /post/:postId/update/upload
so,what i am thought is i can just visit the first path,if i just save the post temporarily and visit the second path if i finally click Submit.

i have to check as if i am doing temporarily saving or confirm saving.

i thought i can determine that by check the next function is null or not,but failed,the next function always got something,even while visiting /posts/:postId/update.

is there any way to determine that?

Comment: I am pretty sure you have `req.url` from which you could understand where the request originated from.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a single reference to the first route's handle and call it in the second:

```
function updatePost(req, res) {
  res.send('Updated');
}

app.post('/posts/:postId/update', updatePost);

app.post('/posts/:postId/upload', function upload(req, res) {
    const upload = req.file; // this property will differ depending upon your upload middleware

    // some app logic

    updatePost(req, res);
});
```

Furthermore, you should consider using [`express.Router`](http://expressjs.com/guide/routing.html) to decouple your routes from your server code.